# How to make a "on/off" button inside a loop react 17

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a loop that render a list of switch button "on/off" inside of it.

Because I'm new at react I followed this tutorial : https://upmostly.com/tutorials/build-a-react-switch-toggle-component and it works great to render one button, but I don't understand how to make it works with a list of button.

For now my code will just switch on/off all button together instead of switch on/off the button that the user will click on.

Switch component:

```js
import React from "react";

const Switch = ({ isOn, handleToggle, onColor }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        checked={isOn} 
        onChange={handleToggle} 
        className="react-switch-checkbox" 
        type="checkbox" />

      <label 
       style={{ background: isOn && onColor }} 
       className="react-switch-label" 
       htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}>
       <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

Loop:

```js
const Categories = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
            {categories &&
              categories.map((categorie) => {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment>
                      <Switch 
                       id={categorie.id} 
                       isOn={value} 
                       onColor="#EF476F" 
                       onChange={() => setValue(!value)} 
                      />
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              })}
 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

Css

```css
/*switch*/
.react-switch-checkbox {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.react-switch-label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.react-switch-label .react-switch-button {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.29);
}

.react-switch-checkbox:checked + .react-switch-label .react-switch-button {
  left: calc(100% - 2px);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.react-switch-label:active .react-switch-button {
  width: 60px;
}
```

I did try to add a id inside the switch component but it doesn't works:

```js
  <input 
        checked={isOn} 
        onChange={handleToggle} 
        className="react-switch-checkbox" 
        type="checkbox" />
        id="id" />
```

```js
  <Switch 
   id={categorie.id} 
   isOn={value} 
   onColor="#EF476F" 
   onChange={() => setValue(!value)} 
   id={categorie.id}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all your switches use the same state of value. I suggest putting the switching functionality inside the switch component directly instead of passing it down as a prop, this would mean every switch would be an individual piece with their own state of value.

Comment: This would be a clean design from a separation of concerns perspective if the SwitchButtons are independent from one another

Comment: Yes I did try it too but unfortunately this is the same result. Can you see any mistake in my code ? https://pastebin.com/fFUqD808

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you should declare the switch status in categories. Maybe make the categories as an array of dictionaries. Or maybe initialize the switch status array at first.Something like

```
const Categories = () => {
  const [switchStatus,setStatus] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    initializeSwithStatus();
  }, []);

  const initializeSwithStatus = () =>{
    let tempArr = [...switchStatus];
    categories && categories.map((item,index) =>{
       tempArr.push(false);
    }
   setStatus(tempArr);
};
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
            {categories &&
              categories.map((categorie,index) => {
                return (
                  <React.Fragment>
                      <Switch 
                       id={categorie.id} 
                       isOn={switchStatus[index]} 
                       onColor="#EF476F" 
                       onChange={() => {
                        let switchStat = [...switchStatus];
                        switchStat[index] = !switchStat[index];
                        setStatus(switchStat);
                      }} 
                      />
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              })}
 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

Again this is one possibility to solve your problem. You can follow another design pattern to resolve this issue.

Comment: I did try your solution but the value of the state seems to be the same for every button anyway

Comment: I've edited my answer. The ```isOn={switchStatus[index]}```, now try it out.